# Reply to comment in the same page not in comments/new path, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, comments

I have created commenting system to provide functions like creating comments and replying them.
I used http://www.sitepoint.com/nested-comments-rails/ guide. Worked just perfect. But in this example to reply to some comment it goes to other path, that is what I want to avoid.

Code so far:
**Advertisement#show** here I want to create reply to comment.

```
<%= comments_tree_for @comments %>

<h1>New comment</h1>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

**_comment.html.rb**

```
<div class="well">
  <h2><%= comment.title %></h2>
  <p class="text-muted"><%= comment.root? ? "Started by" : "Replied by" %> <strong><%= comment.author %></strong> on
    <%= l(comment.created_at, format: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S') %></p>


<blockquote>
  <p><%= comment.body %></p>
</blockquote>

<% from_reply_form ||= nil %>
<% unless from_reply_form %>
  <% if comment.leaf? %>
    <small class="text-muted">There are no replies yet - be the first one to reply!</small>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to 'reply', new_comment_path(comment.id) %></p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

     <%= f.hidden_field :advertisement_id, :value => @advertisement.id%>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id%>
 <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Is there any trustworthy guide to help me ?

Comment: just asking are you hitting the create method when you make a post or you are not?

Comment: @Aaditi Jain Do you mean when I create comment ? Or advertisement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `link_to 'reply', new_comment_path(comment.id)` line creates a hyperlink to new comment page and when clicked it takes you to next page to create the comment. Instead you can replace it with a `div` containing the form the toggles and submits new convo from the same page. Bootstrap comes handy here.

**A Mock up of the idea:**  http://jsfiddle.net/bpya4fce/1/

You can build up using this idea. Hope this helps :)

P.S: Make sure that you fetch the variables required for the form in the `action` of view where you embed the form, i.e if you're embedding the form in `show.html.erb`, ensure the necessary variables are fetched in the `show` action/method of controller. In the earlier scenario, it'll be fetched in the `new` action of the CommentsController.

---

```
<div class="container">
<blockquote>
    <h2>Posted Comment</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum. You can reply to this below.
</blockquote>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
          href="#collapseOne">
          Click to reply
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          ### The comment form comes here ###<br/>
          ### render :partial => 'comment/form'
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted. Hope this example code gives you some idea. 
**Be sure to complete the code and test it :)**

**_comment.html.rb**

```
<% from_reply_form ||= nil %>
<% unless from_reply_form %>
  <% if comment.leaf? %>
    <small class="text-muted">There are no replies yet - be the first one to reply!</small>
  <% end %>
  <!-- HERE adding a hidden DIV that contains a form. -->
  <div class='hidden-reply-form-<%= comment.id%>'>
     <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: {comment: Comment.new} %>
  </div>
  <p><%= link_to 'reply', new_comment_path(comment.id), class: 'reply', id: comment.id %></p>
<% end %>
</div>

<script>
  // HERE use reply link to toggle the hidden div. 
  $(function(){
     $(".reply").click(function(){
           // toggle replying div.
           // .....
     });
})
</script>
```